# Dynamic create/destroy CComboBox

Tags: mfc, combobox

I need to switch between the CBS_DROPDOWN and CBS_DROPDOWNLIST styles at runtime.  It looks like the only way to do this is to re-create the control.

So I have the following code:

```
CRect rect;
m_Combo.GetWindowRect(&rect);
m_Combo.DestroyWindow();
m_Combo.Create(CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP  | WS_VISIBLE, rect, this, IDC_MYCOMBO);
```

But all that happens is the combo disappears.  What am I missing?

EDIT:

Using `ModifyStyle` is not an option because this style cannot be changed at runtime.  The control must be recreated.

EDIT 2:

Okay, so I was in screen coordinates instead of dialog coordinates.

```
CRect rect;
m_Combo.GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);  // SUPER IMPORTANT :)
m_Combo.DestroyWindow();
m_Combo.Create(CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP  | WS_VISIBLE, rect, this, IDC_MYCOMBO);
```

But now, the position is right but the font does not match the dialog font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Won't it just be enough to set the control's font to the dialog font? That is, after immediately after recreating the control

`m_Combo.SetFont(GetFont());`